# Intento instalar react pero presento 6 vulnerabilidades altas. No he logrado actualizarlas. ¿Alguien que me ayude?

Tags: npm, paquetes-npm

```
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

Actualizando las dependencias, realicé primero por `npm audit fix --force` y me aparecen 79 vulnerabilidades más. Intenté actualizarlas una por una, pero no funciona.

Quiero trabajar con este framework para aprender usarlo, pero siempre presento estos problemas.
Ya desinstale el paquete globalmente de react y volví a instalarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahí te está diciendo en perfecto inglés que usar `--force` va a meter cambios en tus librerías que pueden romper cosas (porque se puede volar validaciones de dependencias entre ellas, etc).

Lo clave acá es que entiendas qué es lo que está siendo reportado para que decidas qué hacer.

Te dice que css-select depende de la versión mala de nth-check, y luego muestra toda la cadena de dependencias `react-scripts --> webpack --> plugin-svgo --> svgo --> css-select --> nth-check`. Y te está diciendo, muy claro, que al revisar todas esas dependencias transitivas, cambiar react-scripts a una versión que permita resolver todo esto va a dañar cosas y no tiene cómo resolverlo sin tu intervención.

Entonces, puedes incluir en tu pregunta el `package.json` pra ver si alguien se toma el trabajo de depurar tus dependencias y/o te animas a revisar tú mismo en tus dependencias, peerDependencies y demás, qué es lo que estás incluyendo y en qué versión. Luego vas a ir a ver en el repo oficial [para tu versión](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nth-check?activeTab=versions) y ver ahí qué versión puedes usar. O qué otras librerías debes subir de versión (o bajar) para que todo trabaje junto.

Pero no uses `--force` sin entender qué estás haciendo.

Buena suerte